# Spark:do setup work for executor rather than partition

Tags: java, apache-spark

As we know we can do the setup work for each partition using mapPartition etc. , however I have so many partitions to process in each executor and each partition do the exact setup work. I wonder if I can do the setup work for executor rather than partition so that the partition in the same executor don't have to repeat the setup work.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

1. Use a [broadcast variable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables). This is mostly geared to copying some large structure to every executor, so I'm not sure it applies to your use case. I mention it only because if it does apply to your use case, this is a lot easier to get right.
2. Use a `lazy` value in which you do all your setup work, then just use that value inside your RDD transformations. Since the value won't be needed before the transformation, its evaluation will only be triggered once it reaches the executors. Then, by virtue of `lazy`, it'll only be executed once per JVM instance, so once per executor.

   I'm using this technique in a current project, so I should add a disclaimer: you'll have to code this very carefully to avoid serialization errors... It's very easy to close over something that isn't serializable in your setup code.

## EDIT

I'm sorry for some reason I missed the fact you haven't tagged "Scala" but only "Java". I think the advice I gave remains valid, but you'll have to work a bit to get laziness in there - [although that appears to not be too difficult now that Java 8 has lambdas](http://blog.agiledeveloper.com/2015/07/being-lazy-in-java-like-in-scala.html).

Comment: Thanks Alec. I will give it a shot

Comment: I hava thought of using a broadcast variable, but tihe object I need to broadcast is not a serializable one